# How to get data from MySQL DB between certain dates

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im adding points to a db for when a user does somit on site. 
Alls I would like to do is get the points for the last 7 days and total them.

In my DB I have it saved like: PointsID, PointsUserID, PointsTotal, PointsDate

I guess I just need to figure out the latest date in the db, then minus 7 days, then get the values from between them. Once I have returned the values they will need to be summed so I can output one number.

Thanks, Bonxy

Comment: Do you need to get the points in the last 7 days from current date or the last 7 days that the user got any point?

Comment: Please show us what you have so far.

Comment: What is your date type? Are you using unix time or mysql date ?

Comment: Sorry guys. Im saving it in MySQL date/time. I want to be able to get the last 7 days from the current date using date("D");.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(PointsTotal) FROM TableName WHERE PointsUserID = 'IdInQuestion' AND PointsDate >= Date_Sub(Now(), Interval 7 Day)
```

In the event that you are storing the date as a unix timestamp value (AKA a PHP date value) you would want to convert the one of the two values in the appropriate direction.

for instance you could convert the field to a MySQL datetime value by replacing `PointsDate` with `FROM_UNIXTIME(PointsDate)`. You could also go the other way and convert the results of `DATE_SUB()` by wrapping it all in a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. Both should have equal results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Select * From MyTable Where MyDate Between Date_Sub(Now(), Interval 7 Day) and Now()
```